# Compatibility between PHP and office online 365 SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365

I want to do few things with SharePoint Online 365 and php.

I have a php form with three textbox and when click on submit button by entering data, it should save to custom list which exists in office online 365 SharePoint site.

is it possible to do like this with office Online 365 SharePoint and php compatibility.

With asp.net we can add dll of `microsoft.client.runtime`, do this dll supports in php also.

Please have a look over this link: Is this helpful?

https://gist.github.com/lstak/2404924#file-main-js

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[phpSPO](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) - the PHP Library that allows to perform CRUD operations on SharePoint list data, using an REST/OData based API for SharePoint Online.

The current version supports SharePoint Online using claims based authentication.

### Examples

How to perform authentication in SharePoint Online (SPO):

```
try {
    $client = new SPOClient($url);
    $client->signIn($username,$password);
    echo 'You have authenticated successfully\n';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

How to create SharePoint list item (task):

```
require_once 'SPOClient.php';

$username = 'username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com';
$password = 'password';
$url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/";

createTask($url,$username,$password);

function createTask($url,$username,$password){
    $client = new SPOClient($url);
    $client->signIn($username,$password);
    $listTitle = 'Tasks';
    $list = $client->getList($listTitle);
    $itemProperties = array('Title' => 'Order Approval', 'Body' => 'Order approval task');
    $item = $list->addItem($itemProperties);
}
```

You could find more details by follow this [post](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/05/31/sharepoint-online-client-php/)

> Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library